# Flutter/Dart Scope Problem - Return info needed to prevent Duplicate File Upload?

Tags: flutter, dart, scope, return, future

I've got a button which uploads a file to a server and returns the `oldname` of the file. Before uploading, I'd like to check if the file has already been uploaded. But unfortunately, there seems to be a problem with scope and the `oldname` variable always returns null even if the previous upload was successful. Here's the code;

```
    FlatButton(
            onPressed: () async {
             String oldname;
              if (oldname == null)  {
                   oldname = await uploadAudio(
                   currentuserid: currentuserid,
                   filepath: _current.path);                 
              } else {alertUpLoaded(context);}
            },        
          )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `oldname` will always be `null` since its initialization `String oldname` is within the same build method.

Move `String oldname` above the widget’s build function

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _oldName;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        if (_oldName == null) {
          _oldName = await uploadAudio(currentuserid: currentuserid, filepath: _current.path);
        } else {
          alertUpLoaded(context);
        }
      },
      child: Text("Press Me"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I would've chosen yours HBS  but I got an error on "setState(() => _oldName = val" because apparently the return type 'void' isn't a future or string.

Comment: Yea my bad. No need to call setState. Edited my answer